# Pipeline - TypeError: fit_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with 2 categorical features and plenty of binary features. I'd like to perform label encoding and dimensional reduction within a single step as a pipeline.

My data looks like:

```
data.head()

ID  X0  X1  X10 X100    X101    X102    X103    X104    X105    ... X90 X91 X92 X93 X94 X95 X96 X97 X98 X99
0   0   k   v   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   6   k   t   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
2   7   az  w   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
3   9   az  t   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
4   13  az  v   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
5 rows × 377 columns
```

I've tried:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA, FastICA

le = LabelEncoder()
pca = PCA(n_components=10, random_state=42)
ica = FastICA(n_components=10, random_state=42)

steps = [('LabelEncoder',le), ('PCA',pca), ('FastICA',ica)]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

data = pipeline.fit_transform(data)
```

...which raises:

> TypeError: fit_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were
>   given

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: there are realted issues on github, such that [this one](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12720)  on the matter. It doesn't seem possible to use `LabelEncoder` in a `Pipeline`

Comment: As for my understanding the `LabelEncoder` can only be used on a series and not  on a multidimensional object.